# How to use batch file to append text to filename?

Tags: batch-file, rename

I've created a batch file to move files that are over 30 days old to an archive folder. I would also like to append a string of text to the end of the files that are moved. Here is what I have for moving the files older than 30 days:

```
robocopy "C:\...\Data"  "C:\...\Archives" /move /minage:30
```

That part is working great. Any advice on the best way to add a string of text such as "XYZ" to the end? I.E.  datafile_XYZ.txt

Thank you in advance for any help!

Comment: Robocopy the files then use `REN` to rename the files and take advantage of string concatenation, see [this](http://www.dostips.com/DtTipsStringManipulation.php#Snippets.StringConcatenation)

Answer (score 0):

This could be accomplished with a one-line PowerShell command:

`powershell "Get-ChildItem C:\...\Archives\*.* | Where-Object {$_.Name -notlike '"*_XYZ.*'"} | Foreach-object {Rename-Item -Path $_.FullName -NewName ($_.name -replace '\.', '_XYZ.')}"`

Answer (score 0):

```
forfiles /d -30 /m *txt "cmd /c ren @file @fname_xyz.@ext"
```

more info - http://ss64.com/nt/forfiles.html